# Create geometry from a result of intersection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, polygon, c#, geometry

Split a polygon in half with an extended line

[image]

```
public Ipolygon CreatePolyFromIntersection(Ipolgon polygonA, Ipolygon         bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA, IFeature lmark){
            IConstructLine cLine = new LineClass();
            var parcelSegmentCol=(ISegmentCollection)PolygonA;
            for (int i = 0; i < parcelSegmentCol.SegmentCount; i++) {
            var crntSeg = parcelSegmentCol.Segment[i];
            crntSeg.SpatialReference = lmark.ShapeCopy.SpatialReference;
            cLine.ConstructExtended((ILine)crntSeg, esriSegmentExtension.esriExtendEmbedded);
            var line = (ILine)cLine;
            IPolyline extendedline = new PolylineClass();
            extendedline.FromPoint = line.FromPoint;
            extendedline.ToPoint = line.ToPoint;
            extendedline.SpatialReference = crntSeg.SpatialReference;
            ITopologicalOperator createInter = (ITopologicalOperator)extendedline;
            IElement em2 = new LineElementClass();
            em2.Geometry = extendedline;                                
            var pointsOnPolygonB= (IPointCollection)createInter.Intersect(bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension);
            var point1=pointsOnPolygonB.Point[0];
            var point2=pointsOnPolygonB.Point[1];
            var intersectingSegment = new PolylineClass();
            intersectingSegment.FromPoint = point1;
            intersectingSegment.ToPoint = point1;
    // now I have points on Polygon B, all I have to do is is query those points on the polygon, get their distances on the polygon, and get the subCurve using those distances, I will get a curve, and with this curve I can add the intersectingSegment I created from those 2 points and I will have my polygon any comments ????
```

Comment: The math for extending a line segment is quite simple, yet I suspect that ArcObjects has an Extend method. Constructing a pair of clipping shapes from a line extended outside an envelope should also be a matter of adding three vertices, though I don't think it would be necessary either. Have actually written code to solve the problem? If so, you should add it; if not, you should write it, then add it if you get stuck. As it stands, your coding question is missing code.

Comment: see "extent" and "feature to polygon"

Comment: There is no code yet, I have yet to write it, but before I start I wanted to know if there were interfaces that I should know about that could help. and as for the code it would be hard for me to paste the code here since the answer to my question will solve 10% of what the current tool does :). I will post a chunk of code up there but it would be pointless since it does nothing so far :D.

Comment: Seems that my answer lays in the interface IConstructLine, I can extend it, and then intersect it with the polygon

Comment: Pointless code can't be improved upon.  Put in some effort if you want effort from those volunteers who would help you.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time seeing how far you would want to extend the line. Why aren't the other lines in your example being extended? This seems like it would be difficult to automate in any "meaningful" way.

Comment: after looking through the APIs I came into a solution maybe u can correct me if its not possible.I have a polygon 'A' that is within another polygon "B", polygon A is then casted into segments, and I run through each segment. each segment is then extended into infinity using IconstructLine interface. then I use Itopological operator which will contain the extended line's geometry and will use Intersect() with PolygonB, thus creating 2 points on Polygon B. Now all I have left to do is create a subcurve from those 2 points and merge it with the segment that intersects the polygon.

Comment: I will test this and see how it goes, if it is the desired solution I will post an answer

Comment: @Vince obviously you have not read what I said "There is no code yet, I have yet to write it". I am still gathering ideas before I start writing the code, you can see that I actually came with a solution in my comment read it if your interested or if you have any comments on that solution.

Comment: @Vince here you go, here is some code :D, it is not finished but once it is I will test it, if its working then I will post it as the answer.

Comment: I need to draw your attention to the [Be Nice](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.  The comment you were objecting to was flagged and has been deleted.  I also recommend moving the text of your question out of the picture and out of in-code comments because the former makes it impossible to search and the latter makes it difficult for our volunteer answerers to read.

Comment: Noted, I disagree with you though on the part where I am writing what I want in the picture, if it is against policies i'll take it down, but I think that the picture and text and what I had written up there made the problem very simple for others to answer, I mean take a look  this question was answered in less than 24 hours, and the comments were getting full from day one, not trrying to sound like a mr know it all, but I think the picture did help other members see what I am trying to do :)

Comment: Will a future user needing the same help as you received find this by searching on "easy way to extend the line"?  If that text were not only in your picture then they certainly would.  ["You gotta get this to get us."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort of a fuzzy description of what you're trying to do, hopefully this is what you're after:

```
// much earlier
object gMissing = System.Type.Missing; // I use prefix 'g' for global

public IPolygon CreatePolyFromIntersection(IPolygon polygonA,
    IPolygon bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA,
    IFeature lmark)
{
    IConstructLine cLine = new LineClass();
    ISegmentCollection parcelSegmentCol = (ISegmentCollection)polygonA;
    for (int i = 0; i < parcelSegmentCol.SegmentCount; i++)
    {
        cLine.ConstructExtended((ILine)parcelSegmentCol.Segment[i], esriSegmentExtension.esriExtendEmbedded);
        ILine ExtendedLine = (ILine)cLine; // make the constructed line into a line

        // turn the extended line into a polyline geometry
        IGeometryCollection pCutGeomColl = new PolylineClass();
        IPointCollection pCutPointCollection = new PathClass();
        pCutPointCollection.AddPoint(ExtendedLine.FromPoint, gMissing, gMissing);
        pCutPointCollection.AddPoint(ExtendedLine.ToPoint, gMissing, gMissing);
        pCutGeomColl.AddGeometry((IPath)pCutPointCollection, gMissing, gMissing);
        IGeometry pCutGeom = (IGeometry)pCutGeomColl;

        // make sure you set the spatial reference
        pCutGeom.SpatialReference = lmark.ShapeCopy.SpatialReference;

        // use the ITopologicalOperator to work with the geometries
        ITopologicalOperator3 pCutTopOp = (ITopologicalOperator3)bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA;
        IGeometry pBoundaryLine = pCutTopOp.Boundary; // extracts the polyline that is the boundary of the polygon
        ITopologicalOperator3 pBoundaryTopOp = (ITopologicalOperator3)pBoundaryLine;

        // now find the two intersection points...
        // intersect returns a geometry but by supplying the esriGeometry0Dimension parameter
        // we know that it will be a point or multipoint object... because it's a polygon it 
        // intesect none or multiple times - it will NOT be a point: either null or multipoint.
        IMultipoint pInterPoints = (IMultipoint)pBoundaryTopOp.Intersect(pCutGeom, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension);

        // consider finding if there is in fact an intersection like
        //if (pInterPoints != null)
        // -or-
        //if ((pInterPoints as IPointCollection).PointCount != 0)
        //{

        // now find the result polygons...
        // you could use any one of the ITopologicalOperator operators but I am using ITopologicalOperator3
        // be careful the interface supports your geometry
        IGeometry LeftGeometry;
        IGeometry RightGeometry;
        pCutTopOp.Cut((IPolyline)pCutGeom, out LeftGeometry, out RightGeometry);
        // now you need to decide how to choose one of these to return...
        // let's do it by the biggest area.

        IArea pLeftArea = (IArea)LeftGeometry;
        IArea pRightArea = (IArea)RightGeometry;

        if (pLeftArea.Area > pRightArea.Area)
        {
            // replace the bounary polygon with the left area
            bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA = (IPolygon)LeftGeometry;
        }
        else
        {
            // replace the boundary polygon with the right area
            bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA = (IPolygon)RightGeometry;
        }
        //}
    }
    return bounradyThatcontainsPolylgonA;
}
```

The [ITopologcialOperator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003t6000000) has two handy functions: [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/Intersect_Method/002m000003vs000000/) and [Cut](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/Cut_Method/002m000003vq000000/) which will give you what you're after - you only need to decide which polygon to keep.. as you can see I'm keeping the biggest part, you will need to come up with your own logic if that's not what you want.

You can get the boundary of the polygon with [ITopologicalOperator.Boundary](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/Boundary_Property/002m000003v7000000/) and then intersect with the extended line to get both intersection points, which you indicated you needed, note there could be more than two if the polygon is very odd shaped. You don't need to make both polylines provided the Intersect is done with `esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension` indicating that you want points as output, it should be smart enough to work it out, I added this as a nicety.

BTW: I *really* hate K&R bracer style and unindented blocks - it makes the code *very* hard to read. I know it has nothing to do with execution but when somebody else needs to read your code or you need to go back later it's more difficult to read. If you're using Visual Studio you should be able to Edit::Advanced::Format Document to indent at the very least.

Comment: Your code is the same as mine except the part were we get the polygon section :). Your cutting the polygon into 2 which works perfect. What I did was I got the polygons Exterior ring and used the point of intersection to get the subcurve, and join the intersection line thus getting my polygon :). both answers gave perfect results. Thanks for your answer as well.